# How do I get the current stack setting for a chart in Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a simple bar chart with a few series of data. Until now I had two additional buttons to. One to stack these series, another one to unstack - identical as it is in Apex example.
Both had the same dynamic action with proper java expression:  `$("#chart_count_jet").ojChart({stack: 'on'})` and `$("#chart_count_jet").ojChart({stack: 'on'})`

So now instead of two buttons I think about replacing them to one switch component. In this case I need to use just one dynamic action with simple "If statement" and base on current status of chart do "stack on" or "stack off".
So would you help me please how to check the present status of stack of the series ?

Comment: So is your actual question, "How do I get the current `stack` setting for a chart in Apex?"

Comment: @David - right  exactly this is the question thanks for simplification :)

Comment: Please check if `apex` or `oracle-apex` is the correct tag for the question.